# different results with python requests module and curl

Tags: python, redirect, curl, python-requests

When using **CURL**, I get the result. And it's a `302 redirect`.

```
hhr@hhr:~$ curl -I http://www.vevo.com/watch/kesha/crazy-kids/USRV81300226
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdeFB7I0YH4
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 15:33:41 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 15:33:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

When using **Python requests** module, the result is as follows. And it's a `200 ok`.

```
import requests
import pprint

url = 'http://www.vevo.com/watch/kesha/crazy-kids/USRV81300226'
res = requests.get(url, proxies={'http': '127.0.0.1:8087'}, allow_redirects=False)

print 'status_code: ', res.status_code
print 'response_url: ', res.url
print 'headers: '
pprint.pprint(res.headers)
print 'history: ', res.history
```

And the output:

```
status_code:  200
response_url:  http://www.vevo.com/watch/kesha/crazy-kids/USRV81300226
headers: 
{'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store',
 'connection': 'keep-alive',
 'content-encoding': 'deflate',
 'content-length': '12310',
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
 'date': 'Mon, 17 Jun 2013 16:17:35 GMT',
 'expires': 'Mon, 17 Jun 2013 16:17:35 GMT',
 'pragma': 'no-cache',
 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0',
 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'via': 'HTTP/1.1 GWA',
 'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
 'x-aspnetmvc-version': '3.0',
 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET'}
history:  []
```

Why the results are different?

What can I do in order to get the `Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdeFB7I0YH4` value in **CURL** output using Python?

Comment: You'll need to compare the request headers; the server is responding differently based on the request headers. What headers toggle this behaviour is entirely up to the server, a black box.

Comment: I get 302 with your python code. I omitted `proxies=...` argument.

Comment: @falsetru: interesting; I get a 200.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Maybe www server respond according to client region?

Comment: @MartijnPieters How can I check the request headers?

Comment: @falsetru curl and Python requests are in the same region, so client region is not the reason.

Comment: @falsetru I get 302 now when omitting proxies. The server respond according to client region indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
```

Without `proxies=...`, I got following output.

```
status_code:  302
response_url:  http://www.vevo.com/watch/kesha/crazy-kids/USRV81300226
headers:
{'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store',
 'connection': 'keep-alive',
 'content-length': '159',
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
 'date': 'Mon, 17 Jun 2013 16:32:15 GMT',
 'expires': 'Mon, 17 Jun 2013 16:32:15 GMT',
 'location': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdeFB7I0YH4',
 'pragma': 'no-cache',
 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0',
 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
 'x-aspnetmvc-version': '3.0',
 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET'}
history:  []
```

requests used: 0.13.2

With requests 1.2.3, I got similar result.

Comment: I fix the problem when omitting proxies. Thanks.